# Firebase outbound networking... from where?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Today I found out that I have 2.6KB in "outbound networking". The limit on Spark Plan is 0 and so I get an error like: "100% of your quota has been used (Outbound Networking)" (I'm trying to translate correctly from Italian by the way, I get the message "100% della quota utilizzato. Esegui l'upgrade per evitare l'interruzione del servizio."

My question is: since I'm not making any external request (at least I think so) why is firebase showing me this? My Cloud functions just write to the database or send the client some data. Bytes in outbound go up as I use my functions.. How is this possible?

Comment: Please contact Firebase support directly if something about the Firebase console or its accounting is unclear to you.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support